# Load when scrolled to bottom in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api

Trying to finish my homework and I am working with themoviedb.org. Current value of movies from themoviedb.org is 20 only. How I can load more when scrolled to bottom? I tried some solutions but did not work. And most of solutions are for TableView. Cannot find something useful for CollectionView.

Below is code where I load these 20 movies and can pull to update.

```
import UIKit

class List: UICollectionViewController {

    lazy var refresher: UIRefreshControl = {
        ...
    }()

    @IBOutlet var movieCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

    var movies: [Movie] = [Movie]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        movieCollectionView.refreshControl = refresher
        ...
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        fetchMovies()
    }


// Update Movies List
    @objc func fetchMovies() {
        ViewController.sharedInstance().fetchMovies { (movies) in
            if let movies = movies {
                self.movies = movies
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.movieCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                print("error occured while fetching movies")
            }
        }

        let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(700)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        }
    }


// CollectionView Functions
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movies.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cellReuseIdentifier = "collectionCell"
        let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.poster!.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit

        if let posterPath = movie.posterPath {
            ViewController.sharedInstance().fetchPoster(path: posterPath, size: ViewController.PosterConstants.RowPoster, completion: { (imageData) in
                if let image = imageData {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.poster!.image = image
                    }
                } else {
                    print("error")
                }
            })
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let controller: Detail = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as! Detail
        controller.movie = movies[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        var numberOfSections = 0
        if movies.count > 0 {
            numberOfSections = 1
            collectionView.backgroundView = nil

        } else {
            ...
            noDataLabel.text = "Please wait... I'm thinking..."
            ...
        }
        return numberOfSections
    }


}
```

Comment: implement `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method and fetch next records when it reaches last cell

Comment: one thing is you need to check the response of API because response must contain data for the next page, otherwise, your current implementation makes views fuzzy

Answer (score 0):

You can check this repository
https://github.com/mfmansueli/TMDB-Involves
I create this project last year using tmdb, I don't know if this work yet.

I use infinite scroll in this class:
https://github.com/mfmansueli/TMDB-Involves/blob/master/IMBDInvolves/Scenes/Movies/MoviesViewController.swift

```
extension MoviesViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let height = scrollView.frame.height
    let contentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let reachedBottom = (offset + height == contentSizeHeight)

    if reachedBottom {
        scrollViewDidReachBottom(scrollView)
    }
}

func scrollViewDidReachBottom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    viewModel.input.getUpcomingMovies()
}
}
```